# Formatting of title in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, title

I have the following python code:

```
def plot_only_rel():
    filenames = find_csv_filenames(path)
    for name in filenames:
        sep_names = name.split('_')
        Name = 'Name='+sep_names[0]
        Test = 'Test='+sep_names[2]
        Date = 'Date='+str(sep_names[5])+' '+str(sep_names[4])+' '+str(sep_names[3])
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(atb_mat_2)
    plt.title((Name, Test, Date))
```

However when I print the title on my figure it comes up in the format

> (u'Name=X', u'Test=Ground', 'Date = 8 3 2012')

I have the questions:
Why do I get the 'u'? Howdo I get rid of it along with the brackets and quotation marks?
This also happens when I use suptitle.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

`plt.title` receives a string as it's argument, and you passed in a tuple `(Name, Test, Date)`. Since it expects a string it tried to transform it to string using the tuple's `__str__` method which gave you got output you got. You probably want to do something like:

```
plat.title('{0} {1}, {2}'.format(Name, Test, Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
plt.title(', '.join(Name,Test,Date))
```

Since you are supplying the title as an array, it shows the representation of the array (Tuple actually).
The `u` tells you that it is an `unicode` string.

You could also use format to specify the format even better:

```
plt.title('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(Name, Test, Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python > 3.6 you may even use f-string for easier formatting:

```
plt.title(f'{Name}, {Test}, {Date}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to @Gustave Coste's answer: You can also use lists directly in f-strings

```
s="Santa_Claus_24_12_2021".split("_")
print(f'Name={s[0]}, Test={s[1]}, Date={s[2]} {s[3]} {s[4]}')
```

result: `Name=Santa, Test=Claus, Date=24 12 2021`. Or for your case:

```
plt.title(f'Name={sep_names[0]}, Test={sep_names[2]}, Date={sep_names[5]} {sep_names[4]} {sep_names[3]}')
```